# How do I output details when I use Goland 's Test function ？

Tags: go, goland

```
GOROOT=F:\language\go #gosetup
GOPATH=F:\path\go #gosetup
F:\language\go\bin\go.exe test -c -v -json -o C:\Users\96173\AppData\Local\Temp\___TestRequest.exe test.com/project #gosetup
F:\language\go\bin\go.exe tool test2json -t C:\Users\96173\AppData\Local\Temp\___TestRequest.exe -test.v -test.run ^TesRequest$ #gosetup
```

I want remove the parameters `-c`,beacause i can't see the fmt.Println output.

Answer (score 1):

To run all tests in a folder, select this folder in the Project tool window and press `Ctrl+Shift+F10` or select Run Tests in 'folder' from the context menu.

Resource: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/performing-tests.html#run-tests

[image]

Answer (score -1):

run -> configuration -> Go tool arguments add -v parameter